# Login/Registration errors

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, registration

I am having a problem with both my Login and Registration codes creating the intended cookie and forwarding the login to the member page.

The Error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tplrpgpc/public_html/login.php:64) in /home/tplrpgpc/public_html/login.php on line 93
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tplrpgpc/public_html/login.php:64) in /home/tplrpgpc/public_html/login.php on line 96

This is the code that is causing the error:

```
setcookie("save_user", htmlentities($_POST['username']), $month); 
$login = "INSERT INTO logins (account, ip, success) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."', '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."', 'Yes')";
$add_login = mysql_query($login);
header("location: news.php");
```

The first line is the line 93 error and the ending line is line 96. This is the same code causing errors on both pages. It is not starting the cookie and is not redirecting to news.php. In my database it is showing up as the registration successful and the login complete but like I said is not starting the session and redirecting. Any help would be great.

Edit: I have just realized that it logs in the user but before doing so it shows the error and they have to reclick on the login link in order to go to the members page. I would like this to redirect instead.

Comment: Did you Google your error message(s)? You're obviously outputting before header.

Comment: Pretty common error. Check if you actually sent anything else before the headers. This includes whitespaces.

Find all you need to know here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Yes I have Fred -ii- but I have found only one that deals with setting a cookie, however it does not include it to follow through onto the next set of links that the user clicks through.

Comment: inset `ob_start()` at top of main page before html output

Comment: You could have a byte order mark then in your file(s). Is your file(s) saved in UTF-8 without BOM? @user3262013

Comment: You also could try to drop all closing `?>` tags. You don't really need them, in most cases, unless you're going in and out of PHP. @user3262013

Comment: I forgot my ob_start at the beginning. Thank you Sameer.

Comment: There may not be a need for `ob_start()`. What does `public_html/login.php` say at line 64?

Comment: On my line 64 of login.php I have a opening <?php tag.  That is it.